# stringByEvaluatingJavaScript object has no ID

Tags: javascript, webview, swift3, stringbyevaluatingjavascr

I am using `self.webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.getElementById('username').value = \"\(username)\"")` to put in a username, and it works fine.

A different webpage has this field:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="255" name="user" class="stdWidth" value="">
```

and this field:

```
<input type="password" maxlength="255" password="1" name="pass" class="stdWidth">
```

How would i use `stringByEvaluatingJavaScript` to put text into this field, as it has no ID?

I hace tried `"document.getElementByTagName"` but it didnt work.

The webpage I am trying to input to is: [Link](https://usagym.org/fw/login.html?url=/pages/index.html)

Answer (score 3):

Try like this.you have `class` field so use `document.querySelector()` to select your element.Example below.

```js
var input = document.querySelector(".stdWidth");
input.value = "\"Hello\"";
//add event listener on edit like this..
input.addEventListener('change',function(){
var value = this.value;
console.log(value);//this is current value of your field
});
```

```html
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

**UPDATE**

The `getElementsByTagName()` method returns a collection of all elements in the document with the specified tag name, as a NodeList object.

```js
var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
input[0].value = "\"username\"";
input[1].value = "\"password\"";
```

```html
<input type="text" maxlength="255" name="user" class="stdWidth" value="">
<input type="text" maxlength="255" name="pass" class="stdWidth" value="">
```

Comment: `self.webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.querySelector('.stdWidth').value = \"\(username)\"")` did the job - thanks!

Comment: Yes use `document.querySelector()` because you have `class` field.And then set value as you set like in `id`.

Comment: `<input type="password" maxlength="255" password="1" name="pass" class="stdWidth">` I also want to edit this box, however it has not value - can you also tell me how to edit this?

Comment: yes it is possible to edit you have to handle `change` event on your `textbox`.

Comment: how do i do that?  Can you give me some example code?

Comment: You can see in edited answer.Just added event listener to get your field value on editing.

Comment: `self.webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.getElementByTagName('pass').value = \"\(password)\"")`  How would I update this code to change the pass field above?  Would your code edit the password field or return when the username field is changed?

Comment: if you want to set field blank initially then just remove `input.value = "\"Hello\"";`.

Comment: same way as you did for `username`.

Comment: if you need to save fields values on editing in database then need to use `ajax()`.

Comment: `self.webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.querySelector('.stdWidth').value = \"\(username)\"")
                    self.webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.querySelector('.stdWidth').value = \"\(password)\"")`  This just causes the first field to contain the password, and the password field remains empty

Comment: see this line for pasword.`"document.querySelector('.stdWidth').value = \"\(password)\"")` you have to use new class name for field password.

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: `<input type="password" maxlength="255" name="password" class="pass" value="">'` then `"document.querySelector('.pass').value = \"\(password)\"")` try like this
`

Comment: I can't edit the webpage i'm inputting to - I can't change the class of the password field.   This is the webpage I am putting the fields into   [link](https://usagym.org/fw/login.html?url=/pages/index.html)

Comment: try once like this.. `self.webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.getElementByTagName('input')[1].value = \"\(password)\"")`

Comment: putting that in causes the username field to not work, and doesn't put anything into the password field.

Comment: see edited answer use offset to get your element.Because `document.getElementByTagName()` returns array of elements of tag name.

Comment: The issue is that the pass field doesn't have a 'value' attribute.

Comment: ok..  I still haven't got anything to work though - the username field is setting fine but I can't set the pass field.